# Behind the scenes, when an elephant treads on a mouse

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, weight

What exactly is the thing that causes the mouse to suffer more when an elephant treads on it, despite the fact that they both are exerting an equal force on each other?

A quantitative description would really help :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a string and you hang just enough weight from that string that it's very near breaking, but does not break just yet. Now I ask, "what about if we had two strings in parallel, how much could you hang then?" -- the sane expectation is that you could hang twice as much. This means that the force itself does not tell you how much something breaks, but also the cross-sectional area that the force acts through (the number of strings, in the above case). When we divide force by cross-sectional area we get something much closer to the properties of the actual material, and not just how it happens to be configured. In other words, materials break when the **stresses** get too high, not when the forces do. These forces-divided-by-areas are called "stresses" and they are measured in the same units as pressures are.

The mouse experiences much greater stresses even though the forces are the same, in general because it is smaller. The exact mechanisms require a bit more effort to "peek inside" the biology. For example, the elephant feels much less stress in its bones than the mouse does. Why? Because its bones are frickin' ginormous by comparison. Or for another example, the elephant feels much less stress on its skin. Why? Because it has this very thick hide which rapidly spreads out the impact of the mouse over a much wider surface area, kind of like how a bullet can be made to do less damage if it first hits something which distributes it  over a larger area (like a book or a helmet or a SWAT vest).

An elephant is **built for** these bigger forces, and its biology has chosen solutions like the thicker hide and stronger bones, to both bring the stress back to reasonable levels and to handle higher stresses. That's why it takes so much less damage. If the mouse were made out of indestructible metal, then the elephant might injure its foot but there is no way that it would completely be squished, because those stresses are no higher than the total force of its weight -- and it's built to handle that.

## A cautionary tale for the would-be engineer

This was, so the lore holds, a source of one of the biggest biomedical engineering disasters: tempromandibular joint implants. Your TMJ is a joint that lives in your jaw between your jawbone and your skull: they both connect with these two balls of bone that are covered with cartilage to be super-smooth, and then there is a thin cartilage disk between them, bulging on the outsides, which both balls "roll around in" for lack of a better term. This is why you can move your jaw not just open and closed but also forward and backward and side-to-side.

Well in some people this cartilage disk falls out or breaks or gets disintegrated, and usually the resulting stresses eventually wear out the cartilage on both balls and it leads to excruciating bone-on-bone pain, and the typical treatment is "wire the jaw shut, let them drink through a straw for the rest of their life," which you can imagine is suboptimal. An engineer had a better idea: "I will remake this cartilage disk." I don't know the exact history but the story goes that he built it out of a sort of bag with a gel inside, and the gel was holding little grains of poly-tetrafluoroethylene (PTFE, you may know it by the brand name Teflon). This let him build a plausibly slippery cartilage replacement.

The problem was: he built a large one of these (let's say 10 times larger than the final insert) and found that it was very good at resisting forces, say he built in a safety factor of 50, meaning that the forces actually measured in the jaw were 50 times lower than the forces needed to break the big bag of gel that he made. It seemed perfect so it went on to clinical trials in the small size. **Big** mistake: the stresses are 10 * 10 = 100 times larger in the small scale than in the big scale; that safety factor of 50 was actually a safety factor of 1/2, in other words it was pretty much guaranteed to fail in anyone who used their jaw hard enough.

Well the rest is down to these PTFE particles, we love Teflon because it is super-slippery and it is not usually bio-reactive in any way, but in this case the particles were of just the right size that the body thought it was a "foreign body", like a splinter, that needed to be dissolved away. (As far as I remember, we don't even know why the heck the body decided this!) The body is pretty aggressive about these and does not mind killing some of its own cells to dissolve the splinter once and for all: so it swarmed its white blood cells into FBGCs, "foreign-body giant cells", which dissolve things like splinters but do a lot of collateral damage. Except because the PTFE was so slippery and nonreactive, the attacking FBGCs did not dissolve the particles but merely pushed them away. Meanwhile they dissolved real, important cells trying to chase an enemy that they couldn't hope to catch. People basically lost half of their face due to the implants.

Stress. Force divided by cross-sectional area. Don't make the same mistake and accidentally compare forces across scale-factors when you're trying to figure out whether something will break.

Comment: +1    (although it should be -1  just for scaring me when hip joint replacement time comes ;)  Anyway, I thought the elephant was supposed to run away.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mouse is not noticed by the elephant, and simply treads on it,  I doubt if the mouse will feel much pain, since it will more of an immediate impulse than any prolonged force striking it. To pick up on the comment by tomph, the foot/leg of the elephent is structured to take the weight of a quarter of the mass of the elephent (4  X 1250 kg) = 5000 kg in total,the structures of the mouses' body are designed to deal with the mass of 35 grams.

> A quantitative description would really help :)

A second before the impact, there was a mouse, a second after impact there was a
 2 dimensional stain.

Comment: That's what I'd told my mind. It didn't buy that :p

Comment: If you have the guts (sorry), you could imagine it happening in slow motion, it would probably resemble an  Itchy and Scratchy routine on the Simpsons. Yuk..

Answer (score -1):

The equal forces are acting on different areas. So the distribution of the reaction force  on the elephant's large foot does not make a strong enough sense of  mechanical stress (pain).

On the other hand the mouse's structure is such that there is more force per the same unit of area leading to high mechanical stress in the bones or tissues leading to a higher sense of pain.

Comment: -1 because the answer is wrong, as it implies that, if the elephant foot was as big as a pencil, the elephant would feel a much greater pain than the mouse. It is not the difference in the areas, but the difference in the body structure and the mass of the two animals.

Comment: I thought that the force per unit area on the different bodies caused different stresses